# In a Android gradle build, how to change the package name by build type?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In a Android gradle build, I can simply let the build "overwrite" the package name by flavor like so:

```
productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId "net.company.appname.free"
    }

    paid {
        applicationId "net.company.appname.paid"
    }
}
```

Can I do the same by build type?

It looks like I can only add suffixes:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
}
    release {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, no. What is your use case?

Comment: Release build for client, debug app for internal use with a different package convention. You can surely argue that I SHOULD use the suffix in this case, but still... this seems like an odd limitation.

Comment: `packageNameSuffix` is deprecated, use `applicationIdSuffix` instead

Comment: Updated to use application[...] instead of packageName[...]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit late on with the answer, but you could have a common part of the applicationID defined such as:

```
android { 
  defaultConfig { 
    applicationId 'net.company.appname'
    ...
  }
}
```

and have your flavours specify the applicationIdSuffix as in your example, so that'd give you the 'net.company.appname.debug' and 'net.company.appname.release' or whatever you say you want the suffix to be.

Answer (score 0):

It actually does, if you build the .apk the package will be

for free flavor and debug build type (with your buildType config):
    net.company.appname.free.debug

for the paid :
   net.company.appname.paid.debug

it adds the suffix to the package name. That is why release does not use to have sufix so it has the package "raw". That also allows you to have multiple build types from every flavor on the same device installed at the same time